# Multiple Polymorphic Model in Rails

Tags: database, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism

Hey So i have a basic schema that I am implementing.  Here are the basic Models

```
User - Public Free User of App
Organization - Subscribes to app, has employees
Employee - Belongs to an organization
```

Here are my polymorphic parts

```
Post - Can be made by employees or users
Image - Multiple can be attached to either posts or comments
Comment - Can be added to images or posts by either employees or users
```

Users and Employees are distinct.

The polymorphic image is done.  Where i am having trouble is the comment part.  How do i set this up so that the comment can be associated with either images or posts and can be posted by either employees or users.  Here is what i have so far.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable 
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

This sets it up so that the comment can belong to the post or image, how do i set it up so that the employee/user can have many comments as they add them?  Or should i just split this up into EmployeeComments and UserComments.

It seems like i will need another table that will host the polymorphic ownership association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to add another polymorphic `belongs_to` association to the `Comment` model which will represent the author of the comment.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :authorable, :polymorphic => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :authorable
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :authorable
end
```